# как с помощью localStorage сделать так чтобы теги <p> создаваемые в JavaScript не исчезали после перезагрузки? пожалуйста, без jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

js

```
function fuf() {
    let ghj = document.querySelector('body');
    ghj.innerHTML += "<p>приветик</p>";
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="fyf()">
    <button onclick="fuf()">кликЕР</button>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: При добавлении складывайте в сторадж, при загрузке -берите из стораджа, если он не пуст. В чём сложность?

Comment: не умею, если вам не сложно можете написать как это будет выглядеть

Comment: Вы же уже упомянули localStorage. Значит вы про него в курсе. Всё что вам нужно, это прочитать описание метода set и get. Всё. Разобраться в этом - дело пяти-десяти минут. Для ДЖУНА, а не для мегасуперпрофи

Comment: Для Джуна в локале разобраться 5 минут? Ну хз, я бы день дал минимум, неделя максимум. Понять-то принцип можно, но пока сам на практике не испытаешь, не столкнешься с проблемами и не найдешь их решения, с локалом работать придётся сложно.. Ну короче в слепую, вроде синтаксис понял, делаешь, а там какой-то  object например.

Comment: Ну и джун не знающий локал, врятле джун, скорее  pre

Comment: @WalkMess использовать сеттер и геттер действительно сложно. Действительно, надо 5 высших образований, 100 часов практики и неделя медитации. Был не прав, соре

Comment: Шутите, это хорошо.

Comment: А если серьёзно, на всё нужно время. 5 минут, это если человек язык знает и владеет им, но с локалом столкнулся впервые, как раз достаточно быстро прочитать и действовать. А если  pre,  то конечно время нужно больше. А что бы  junior javaScript  local  не знал, я с таким не сталкивался.

Answer (score 3):

В localStorage можно хранить только строку и у него есть методы setItem и getItem
соответственно чтобы сохранить тэг используем метод setItem [документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
localStorage.set('key', "<p>приветик</p>")
```

Чтобы получить используем `localStorage.get('key')`

И получаем вот такой код

```
function fuf() {
    let ghj = document.querySelector('body');
    const element = "<p>приветик</p>";
    localStorage.setItem('key', element)
    ghj.innerHTML += localStorage.getItem('key');
}
```

Этот код далеко не идеален, но я думаю будет понятно как работает localStorage